# Socket Program Hangs

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I'm trying to get some basic networking going in python. Here's the snippet of the program that does the actual communication:

**Client Side**

```
    # open socket and connect to port
            sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
            sock.connect((regHost, regPort))

            # prepare flos for data
            outFlo = sock.makefile(mode='w')
            inFlo = sock.makefile(mode='r')

            outFlo.write(queryString)
            outFlo.flush()
            print "finished writing"

            tmp = inFlo.readline()
            print tmp

            outFlo.close()
            inFlo.close()
            sock.close()
```

**Server Side**

```
        print 'Spawned thread'
        inFlo = self.sock.makefile(mode='r')
        outFlo = self.sock.makefile(mode='w')

        outFlo.write('test writing\n')
        outFlo.flush()

        inFlo.close()
        outFlo.close()
        self.sock.close()
        print 'Closed socket'
        print 'Exiting thread'
```

The program seems to be hanging on the call to inFlo.readline() in the client side. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was that I forgot to add a \n at the end of one of my strings. Due to that, the program was hanging on the call to inFlo.readline().